# how do i reference multiple models from a single field with sequelize-typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

i want to have multiple `Address` for any of `Person`, `Location`, or `Place` and possibly other entity types in the future. i would like to have a single field on my `Address` model which points to the `id` of whichever thing that address relates to without having to have `personId` and `locationId` and `placeId` etc... on every `Address` when they would only ever use one of those.

my table structure looks like this:

`addresses.entityId => people.id | locations.id | places.id`

how do i model this with `@ForeignKey` in [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript)?

my models look like this:

```
@Table
class Address extends Model<Address> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id: string;

  @ForeignKey // ... ??
  entityId: string;
}

@Table
class Person extends Model<Person> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id: string;
}

@Table
class Location extends Model<Location> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id: string;
}

@Table
class Place extends Model<Place> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
  })
  id: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom decorator can be given multiple times in this case of Sequelize Typescript, So if you want Refer a column to multiple model then you can give  @ForeignKey multiple times like this snippet i gave.
You Can do something like this:

```
@Table
class Address extends Model<Address> {
    @Column({
      type: DataType.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4
    })
    id: string;
    @ForeignKey(() => Person)
    @ForeignKey(() => Location)
    @ForeignKey(() => Place)
    @Column({})
    public entityId: string;
}
```

Reference:
[Sequelize Typescript Documentation](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#foreignkey-belongsto-hasmany-hasone-belongstomany-api)